# Footer not going to bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

I have a footer at http://puppetweb.ca/play/ and you see the categories list on the left is longer then the actual browser window. I'd like to make the footer attach to the bottom of the page not the window, but I can't seem to figure it out? Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean you want the footer to always be visible at the bottom of the viewport, regardless of scroll position?

Comment: can you post the original CSS and HTML that were pertinent to this question?  Without the problematic code in your your link, this question isn't useful to anyone else.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are there not just to provide you with a solution, but to provide future users with a similar issue a solution as well. Judging by the `/play` part of the url, that url looks volatile and is only useful for the problem at hand. When that link dies it removes the usefulness of the question and the answer for other users of the site. In future, please provide sample code of what isn't working, not just a link to the site you're currently working on. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the footer a `position:static;` CSS property and a `clear:both;` CSS property:

```
#footer {
    position:static;
    clear:both;
}
```

Since the default positioning is static, you could also just remove all the position-related properties:

```
/* play, line 432 */
#footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #272433;
/*    bottom: 0; /* REMOVED */
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
/*    position: absolute; /* REMOVED */
    text-align: center;
    width: 92%;
    clear:both; /* ADDED... could probably also be `clear:left` */
}
```

The problem arises because most of the elements in your document are floating left. But floating elements are [outside the normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

[image: Image showing a floating image that overlaps the borders of two paragraphs: the borders are interrupted by the image. From the w3c Visual Formatting model.]

For more information, see the [w3c's Visual Formatting Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html).

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (by clicking [the green tick](http://www.mitalia.net/images/so/accepted_tick.png)) if it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

When inspecting the CSS property of the #footer element I see

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
```

Try removing the margin-top property. What the CSS is trying to do is assign a value of 0 to the top and to the bottom pulling the element into the middle of the page.

Comment: Nope no luck, I changed margin:0 auto; to margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto; and no change. I also removed my css reset to see if that was the issue, and no luck. Hrm......

Answer (score 0):

reduce the widths of both 'grid_10' and set them to float left. remove the postion of fixed from the footer and set 'clear : both' so that it doesn't float around the two grid_10